# Who shot Bill Cutting 'The Butcher' in the theater?

Tags: plot-explanation, gangs-of-new-york

Who was the man who shot Bill 'The Butcher' in the theater? I suppose he was priest Vallon's friend, but he wasn't shown before. And what was he saying while he was dying? Was he actually praying or saying something to Amsterdam in some other language?

Answer (score 3):

### **An unnamed assassin**

The IMDB [cast list](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217505/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) has him as 'Assassin', played by [Bronco McLoughlin](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0572928/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t63)

**Who was he?** Based on his attempt on Bill's life, and the cross he carries, it seems likely that he was linked with the Dead Rabbits, and was waiting for an opportune moment to kill Bill, possibly in revenge for the murder of Priest Vallon.

**What was he saying?** There are several versions of the [script](https://sfy.ru/?script=gangs_of_new_york_ds) and [transcripts](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/g/gangs-of-new-york-script-transcript.html) online that I can find, but none indicate exactly what he is saying as he dies.

**Was he praying?** Probably. As a religious man he most likely was making peace with God. What prayer it was exactly, we'll likely never know. However, the [Catholic News Agency](http://www.catholicnewsagency.com/resources/prayers/circumstantial-prayers-and-blessings/prayers-at-the-time-of-death/) has a list of Prayers at the Time of Death, so potentially the answer could be there.

[image: Bronco McLoughlin]